# How to place greek alphabet in the naming of facet_grid in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Let say I have below `histogram`-

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Type=c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",4000)),
                 Value=c(rnorm(1000,mean=25,sd=10),rchisq(4000,15)))
# you start here...
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Value))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..,fill=Type),color="grey80")+
  facet_grid(Type~.)
```

Now, I want to rename the `facet_grid` i.e. instead of `A` and `B`, I want to place `\sigma_1` and `\sigma_2` in actual `greek` alphabet (`1 & 2` being suffix)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Any pointer will be highly helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use plotmath expressions in combination with `label_parsed()` as the facet's `labeller` argument.

```r
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Type=c(rep("A",1000),rep("B",4000)),
                 Value=c(rnorm(1000,mean=25,sd=10),rchisq(4000,15)))
library(ggplot2)

df$label <- ifelse(df$Type == "A", "sigma~1", "sigma~2")

ggplot(df, aes(x=Value))+
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..,fill=Type),color="grey80")+
  facet_grid(label~., labeller = label_parsed)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how can I make (1 and 2) in subscript?

Comment: @Bogaso You change `"sigma~1"` to `"sigma[1]"`. See `help("plotmath")`